# Is the use of '1991-9' annoying/confusing?

Tags: abbreviations, numerals

As a native, do you understand what '1991-9' means? Do you find it annoying or confusing?

Maybe, '1991-99' would be better? '1991-1999' contains too many symbols, I would like to shorten it a bit.

Comment: I find it perfectly understandable, but, being about numerals, this is not really an English language question!

Comment: Numerals are part of any, I assume, language

Comment: The way dates are written is not specific to English.

Comment: @KateBunting Sure it is. Moreover it's specific to regional conventions. Americans write MM/DD/YY while Brits write DD/MM/YY. Germans are more likely to use periods than slashes. This is a perfectly on-topic subject.

Comment: It is specific to English.  What I write 2019-11-21 would typically be written 2019年11月21日 in Japanese, for example.

Comment: Not enough context. Numbers can refer to many different things.

Comment: Date 11 more to go...

Comment: What does it have to do with Japanese? In Japanese, we don't use such a spelling 1991-9. It is very confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern 1991-9 should be familiar to most English speakers because this format is sometimes used when referencing page numbers. For example, "pp. 23-5" means pages 23 through 25. But I don't recall seeing this form used for years. 1991-99 looks much more normal. Even more normal (and shorter) in casual writing is *'91-'99* if it is not necessary to specify the century.

Comment: But! An this is important: you would still advise against writing, for example, 1910-2, right?, because you wouldn't say 'nineteen ten, two', you'd say 'nineteen ten, twelve' (if not 'nineteen ten, nineteen twelve') and you can't say 'twelve' unless there's '1' written, am I right?

Comment: Honestly I'd advise against writing years this way at all, regardless of spoken form. 1910-12 is clearer.